# Как отслеживать нажатия по определенной часть моего CustomView?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, customview

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добрый день.

Вопрос такой - есть кастомная вью. Круг, поделенные на 4 части разных цветов. Хочу отслеживать нажатие по области, в которую входит один цвет, и исходя из этого уже делать дальнейшую обработку.
Проблема в том, что я не понимаю, как это реализовать. Я могу забирать координаты по нажатию, но мне нужно записать куда то область, в которую входит например зеленый цвет, и обработать (если координаты входят в эту область, то...какие то действия).

Подскажите, как это реализовать?

Comment: Можете попробовать просто математикой, если нет средств проще...сначала проверяете попадание в общую окружность, потом, если попали, то в центральную, потом, если не попали, то определяете область, куда кликнули (координаты сравниваются с разницей от центра, то есть надо определить долю окружности, куда попали). Нужна только формула попадания точки в окружность.

Comment: `R^2>x^2+y^2 && x^2+y^2>r^2 && x<0 && y<0` - попадание в синюю часть. `x` и `y` координаты относительно центра, `R` и `r` - радиусы. вроде так.

Answer (score 0):

Начиная с API 19 для детектирования нажатия на любые сложные формы, в том числе и сектор круга, можно использовать такой подход. Создаем `Path` области, им же, как правило, и рисуем. При касании создаем второй тестовый `Path` - квадрат в точке касания размером в один пиксель. Методом op делаем операцию `INTERSECT` оставляя общую область, далее если проверочный `Path` не пустой - значит мы нажали на нужной области. Пример который протестировал. Обратите внимание как создается сектор круга, в инете я пример не нашел.

```
public class ViewPath extends View{
    Path path;
    Paint paint;
    public ViewPath( Context context ){
        super( context );
        path = new Path();
        RectF rect = new RectF(200,100,200+500,100+500);
        path.moveTo( rect.centerX(), rect.centerY() );
        path.arcTo( rect, 0, 90, false );
        paint = new Paint( Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG );
        paint.setColor( 0xfff00000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw( Canvas canvas ){
        super.onDraw( canvas );
        canvas.drawPath( path, paint );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent( MotionEvent event ){
        if( event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ){
            Path path_test = new Path();
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();
            path_test.addRect( x, y, x+1, y+1, Path.Direction.CW );
            path_test.op( path, Path.Op.INTERSECT );
            if( !path_test.isEmpty() ){
                Toast.makeText( this.getContext(), "OK!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            }
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent( event );
    }
}
```